# Manejo de datos en memoria

Tags: java, cache, patrones-de-diseño

me encuentro en un dilema el cual agradeceria de su colaboración, tengo varios servicios web que cada vez que se invocan deben hacer un acceso a base de datos para traer una información, estos datos son suceptibles de modificación pero no a corto tiempo, para disminuir el acceso a base de datos mi objetivo es construir una "especie" de cache con esta información. La duda es cual sería la mejor forma de hacerlo, he estado pensando en implementar un patron singlenton que cargue los datos en una variable estatica y a esta se acceda en el momento que sea requerido (solo lectura), sin embargo se que esto puede llevar a varios problemas de acceso a la variable como sincronización o concurrencia. No es mi deseo hacer una implementación de un framework como EHCahe. Agradezco de su orientación, guia y que modelo puedo seguir.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta pertenecería a una comunidad distinta del Stack ... no estoy seguro.

Comment: Hola isaac! esta bueno lo que queres hacer. Por un lado el patrón singleton te va a ayudar en cuanto a la performance, pero para realizar lo del caché dependerta de la tecnología que estés utilizando. Te pregunto: que lenguaje y framework utilizas para tus servicios?

Comment: @FrancoGallo el lenguaje es java 8 los servicios en JAX-RS

Comment: @PakLeiChong, Me puede indicar a que comunidad, la verdad solo interactuo con esta, si debe ir en otra muevo la pregunta allá, Muchas gracias

Comment: Tu idea del singleton no está mal, pero la variable donde cacheas los datos la haces privada a la clase singleton y no estática (no tiene sentido) y luego permites solo acceso de lectura con un método *get*. Así te solucionas el problema de sincronización - si nadie modifica los datos y solo los lee no hay necesidad de sincronizar ¿no? La modificación la debes hacer por otro lado. El problema que veo es que debes avisar a tu singleton que se han modificado los datos para recargar la cache. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Después de deliverar un rato y leer el comentario de @Evgeni Enchev, y teniendo en cuenta que solo se requiere para read-only y su objetivo es disminuir los accesos a base de datos, entonces, he creado una clase Singlenton super básica.

```
public final class Cache {

    private final Map<String, Map<String, String>> cache;
    private static Cache instancia;

    private Cache() {

        this.cache = unaClase.metodoQueObtieneLasConfiguraciones();

    }

    public static Cache getInstancia() {
        if(instancia == null) {
            instancia = new ConfiguracionCache();
        }
        return instancia;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParametrosXConfiguracion(String configuracion){
        return this.cache.get(configuracion);
    }

    public String getValorParametro(String configuracion, String parametro) {
        return getParametrosXConfiguracion(configuracion).get(parametro);
    }
}
```

Y la implementación sería

```
Cache cache = Cahe.getInstancia();
Map<String, String> mapa = cache.getParametrosXConfiguracion("NOMBRE_CONFIGURACION");
```

A futuro, no muy lejano espero, codificare algo mejor y más flexible.